# Тестирование redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, jest, redux-thunk, enzyme

Помогите правильно протестировать. Вариант тестирования - с mock.

```
export const checkStatus = (response) => {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  }
  if (response.status === 403) {
    const cloneResponse = response.clone();
    cloneResponse.json().then((json) => {
      if (json.detail === 'Your IP is not allowed for this API.') {
        history.push(createInternationalUrl(frontendUrls.urlOnlyInUSA));
      }
    });
    const error = new Error(response.statusText);
    error.response = response;
    throw error;
  } else {
    if (response.status >= 500) { history.push(createInternationalUrl(frontendUrls.urlError)); }
    if (response.status === 401) { store.dispatch(doLogout(true)); }
    const error = new Error(response.statusText);
    error.response = response;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('ERR', response);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Наконец решил этот тест с использованием некоторых стандартных конструкций. Покрытие вышло в пределах 80% всего 2 строки остались не покрытыми и две конструкции If (с ошибками 500 и 401).

```
import { checkStatus } from 'modules/core/utils';
import { Response } from 'node-fetch';

describe('Check error in checkStatus', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    window.history.pushState({}, 'Page Title', '/');
  });
  it('CheckStatus should catch an ERR', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    try {
      await checkStatus();
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error).toBeInstanceOf(Error);
    }
  });
  it('CheckStatus should catch 403', async () => {
    expect.assertions(2);
    try {
      const response403 = new Response(null, { status: 403 });
      await checkStatus(response403);
    } catch (status) {
      expect(status).toBeInstanceOf(Error);
      expect(status.response).toBeInstanceOf(Response);
    }
  });
  it('CheckStatus should catch 200', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    const response200 = new Response(null, { status: 204 });
    const response = checkStatus(response200);
    expect(response).toBeInstanceOf(Response);
  });
});
```